# Can I call event listener after n seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, inappbrowser

I have a function

```
var inApp = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(ln, '_blank', 'location=no');
inApp.addEventListener('loadstop', function(){
    inApp.insertCSS({
        file: 'http://istudy.com.pk/api/hide.css'
    },onSuccess);
});
```

I want to insert the CSS after `n seconds` instead of `loadstop`. Is it possible? How can I achieve that?

Comment: `setTimeout` inside the event listener - or you want something else?

Comment: I just want to insert the css after n seconds. Loadstop take allot of time.

Comment: so - `setTimeout` after the InApp call - wouldn't that do the trick?

Comment: Something like inApp.insertAfter3seconds(function) or something.

Comment: yes, can use `setTimeout()` to create delay & `setInterval()` to perform repeatedly and also could perform hard refresh or stop page refresh easily.

Comment: Can any1 provide me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setTimout(function(){
   inApp.insertCSS({
       file: 'http://istudy.com.pk/api/hide.css'
   },onSuccess);
},3000) // 3000 milliseconds  = 3 seconds
```

but this will only work if `inApp` is defined at time of execution